# Cargar una pagina en un iframe con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo un problema al intentar cargar unos iframes con JS.

Estoy creando una aplicacion con ***talentls*** en la cual tengo que insertar varias ventanas a través de `iframe`, pero en la opción de `javascript` si introduzco 2 funciones para insertar el iframe (un `iframe` para la home y otro para otra ventana), dichas funciones me dan conflicto

**JS del Iframe de la home**

```
window.onload = function(){
   var link = "https://smartwateracademy.com/video/mivideo.php"
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.frameBorder=0;
   iframe.width="75%";
   iframe.height="450px";
   iframe.style="position: absolute; left: 13%; margin-top: 33px;";
   iframe.id="randomid";
   iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
   document.getElementById("video-academy").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

**Iframe de un formulario de con tacto**

```
    //Email function
window.onload = function(){
    var mail = "https://smartwateracademy.com/form/formulario.html"
    var form = document.createElement('iframe');
    form.frameBorder=0;
    form.width="75%";
    form.height="750px";
   form.style="position: absolute; left: 13%; margin-top: 33px;";
    form.id="randomid";
    form.setAttribute("src", mail);
    document.getElementById("form_mail").appendChild(form);
}
```

Al poner las 2 funciones en la misma ventana de js, si pongo primero la función del iframe del video y después la del formulario, el vídeo de la home no se ve y si lo pongo al contrario, es el formulario el que no aparece en la ventana correspondiente.

Alguien sabe cómo podría crear los 2 iframes en un mismo archivo js para que no me de conflicto y se me carguen los 2 en sus respectivas ventanas?

Comment: Podrías separar el código de las funciones anónimas y lo metes en funciones normales. Despues en el onload las podrias llamar a ambas `window.onload = function(){iframeHome();iframeContacto();}` así tendrías solo un `windows.onload`

Comment: correcto. De la otra manera estarías pisando el valor que le das a window.onload al hacer varias funciones anonimas y solo se ejecutaría la última. Ahora te lo desarrollo en una respuesta.

Comment: acabo de hacer lo que me comentas, crear las 2 funciones `function iframeHome(){codigo sin windows.onload}` y `function iframeContacto(){codigo sin windows.onload}` y de ahí hacer la llamada a las funciones `window.onload = function(){iframeHome();iframeContacto();}` pero me sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: mira mi respuesta. Y comprueba si has escrito algo mal, igual no me he explicado bien por los comentarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Del mismo modo que si haces:

```js
var a = 1;
var a = 2;

console.log("a="+a); //Output: [a=2]
```

`a` sería siempre 2, por que estarías pisando el valor. 
Por eso solo tiene en cuenta el último.

Una manera de hacerlo sería:

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    iframeHome();
    iframeContacto();
    //Mas funciones/codigo que necesites se ejecute en el onload
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    iframeHome();
    iframeContacto();
    //Mas funciones/codigo que necesites se ejecute en el onload
});
```

Puedes ver como asignar multiples funcion al evento onload: [Multiple onload functions](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm)

---

**Snippet ejemplo con iframes:**

```js
/*  jQuery:
$(window).ready(function(){
    iframeHome();
    iframeContacto();
});
*/

window.onload = function(){
    if(document.getElementById("video-academy")){
      iframeHome();
    }
    if(document.getElementById("form_mail")){
      iframeContacto();
    }
    //Mas funciones/codigo que necesites se ejecute en el onload
}

/* Mal
window.onload = function(){
  iframeHome();
}
window.onload = function(){
  iframeContacto();
}*/


function iframeHome(){
    var link = "https://google.com/"
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.frameBorder=0;
    iframe.width="75%";
    iframe.height="150px";
    iframe.style="position: absolute; left: 13%; margin-top: 33px;";
    iframe.id="randomid";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
    document.getElementById("video-academy").appendChild(iframe);
}

function iframeContacto(){
    var mail = "https://google.es/"
    var form = document.createElement('iframe');
    form.frameBorder=0;
    form.width="75%";
    form.height="350px";
    form.style="position: absolute; left: 13%; margin-top: 33px;";
    form.id="randomid2";
    form.setAttribute("src", mail);
    document.getElementById("form_mail").appendChild(form);
}
```

```css
#video-academy {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150px;
}

#form_mail {
  width: 75%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video-academy"></div>
<div id="form_mail"></div>
```

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer lo mismo que me comentas, creando las 2 funciones y haciendo la llamada correspondiente con Javascript `window.onload = function(){iframeHome();iframeContacto();}` pero me pasa lo mismo, me carga solo un `iframe`

Comment: Puede ser que me esté dando el error porque el iframeHome(); se llama desde la home y el iframeContacto(); se llame desde la ventana de contacto?

Comment: @derek ¿Puedes editar la pregunta con mas información del código? No me hago la idea de como tienes la estructura de las ventanas :/

Comment: @derek ¿Te esta sacando algún error en consola?¿Ambas ventanas tienen los contenedores `form_mail` y `video-academy` ? Si no es así te estará dando un error al hacer el `appendChild`. Entonces tendrias que comprobar si en esa ventana existe ese contenedor  antes de llamar a la funcion del iframe o antes del `appendChild`

Comment: el error que me está saliendo por consola cuando entro a la home es este : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of nullat iframeContacto (homepage_id:1,type:home,display:external:681) at window.onload (homepage_id:1,type:home,display:external:660)`

Comment: en la home está llamado el iframe del video `<div id="video-academy" class="video"></div>` el cual me carga bien, pero en ventana de "be an instructor" donde introduzco el `div` del formulario `<div id="form_mail"></div>` no me carga nada

Comment: @derek efectivamente es lo que he puesto en mi comentario. He editado el snippet de mi respuesta con las comprobaciones. Tienes que comprobar que exista en esa pantalla el contenedor antes de llamar a la función.

Comment: Ok, ya modifiqué el js como me lo pusiste con los if() y ya me funcionó y se me cargan los 2 iframes